# Tensorflow Session Memory Leak

Tags: session, memory-leaks, tensorflow, objective-c++

I am using the tensorlfow C++ API and I have linked the tensor flow framework to perform a prediction using an inference.pb file.

The inference works but I have a Memory leak which (according to instruments) is linked to the session->Close().

My function is:

```
- (double) MLPredictionObjC: (float[24]) inputFeatures {
    double results[]={0.0};

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"inference84" ofType:@"pb"];

    if ([self loadGraphFromPath:path] && [self createSession]) {
        double resultsP = [self predictML:inputFeatures];
        session->Close();
        return resultsP;
    }
    return *results;
}
```

// the other functions associated with loading and creating the session are:

```
- (BOOL)loadGraphFromPath:(NSString *)path  
{
    ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), path.fileSystemRepresentation, &graph);
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)createSession
{
    tensorflow::SessionOptions options;
    tensorflow::NewSession(options, &session);
    session->Create(graph);
    return YES;
}
```

I am not sure how to resolve this? should I be using std::unique_ptr session?

Comment: Point of clarification -- your question is marked C++, but is this Objective-C or Objective-C++?

Comment: In the first block of code, why not close the seesion in both cases. You have "session->Close()" in the code inside the if but not before the "return *results"... if Close() is needed to destruct your sessions and the session is no longer needed once you return the results it would make sense to do so.

Comment: @George that wouldn't make a difference as the session is created in the if statement. I have tried it either way just to make sure I'm not missing anything. But the leak is still there.

Comment: @jwimberley thank you. It is Objective-C++, but we are using the tensor flow C++ API

Comment: @FerasAS Ah, fair enough, didn't read the code carefully enough. You might try posting this as an issue on the github page of the API, might be easier to find help that way...

Comment: @George thanks. I have, but I thought I'd try Stack Overflow as well.